# MongoDB Collection Data Storing in File process

Tags: mongodb

If I want to take the backup of MongoDB data files and transfer it to a different server how can we do that? In the data path, I can see a lot of files are there with the prefix collection, index, and ending with *.wt
Tried with all files but the service got stopped.

I'm trying to take the data from version 3.2 and want to restore the data in version 5

By using mongo import and export it's working. But the challenge is it can not be done in production data as the data size is 8TB+
For that looking for some solution if we can copy the data files only from the data path and send it to the version 5 data path.

Comment: How fast is the 8TB of data changing, where physically is the 3.2 housed (cloud, on-prem, desktop, etc.), and where is the 5.0 target housed?

Comment: 8TB is in one server and is in version 3.2 now in the aws and version 5 is newly installed in a different server in the same AZ

Comment: Anything for this?

Comment: How fast is the 8TB changing?

Comment: We've done it from Snapshot and it's working fine now, for 8.5TB it took 4 hours.

Comment: So are you ... done?   If so, please self-answer your question.

Comment: Yes, today will update as self answer